# Generic functions on objects with multiple classes

Tags: r

I am interested to write a generic method that behaves based on multiple class type of the same object. For example, say we have the following:

```
redApple <- function(){
 structure(list(), class = c("apple", "red"))
}

greenApple <- function(){
 structure(list(), class = c("apple", "green"))
}

eat <- function(x)UseMethod("eat")
eat.apple <- function(x)  print("Eating apple")

color <- function(x) UseMethod("color")
color.red <- function(x) print("my food is red")
color.green <- function(x) print("my food is green")
```

Now we create the following objects:

```
obj1 <- redApple()
obj2 <- greenApple()
```

Here `color(obj1)` prints `my food is red` and `color(obj2)` prints `my food is green`, while both `eat(obj1)` and `eat(obj2)` print `Eating apple`.

Now I'd like my generic function behave differently for `obj1` and `obj2`. For example I'd like `eat(obj1)` to print `Eating red apple` and `eat(obj2)` to print `Eating green apple`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the class of the object passed to the function and make cases accordingly:

```
eat.apple <- function(x)  
{
  if("green" %in% class(x)) print("Eating green apple")
  else if("red" %in% class(x)) print("Eating red apple")
  else print("Eating generic apple!")
}

##addition

eat.green <- function(x)  
{
  print("Eating green apple")
}

eat.red <- function(x)  
{
  print("Eating red apple")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, doesn't this violate the open/close principle in OO programming? Because if I later need to add a third class pinkApple, then I will have to modify my generic function

Comment: Yes it does. But if you need to check for 2 classes somewhere you will break it anyway in my opinion. Otherwise you could just define `eat.green`, but this will then be used for every object with class ´green´ independent of it's secondary class e.g `apple` or `pear`. //EDIT: I've added generics for classes `red` and `green` to my solution.